# Summary function in HAVING clause in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following query which returns a customer's username, the year and half-year, a count of bets for the first semi-year, a count of bets for the second semi-year and a profit calc.

> proc sql;

```
  create table avg
  as
  select 
  username as username,
  year(datepart(betdate))*10 + floor( (qtr(datepart(betdate))+1)/2) as yearsemiyear, 
  count(bet_id) as betcount,

  sum( case when floor( (qtr(datepart(betdate))+1)/2) = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as firstHalfBetcount,
  sum( case when floor( (qtr(datepart(betdate))+1)/2) = 2 then 1 else 0 end ) as secondHalfBetcount,

  round(mean((winnings - stake) / stake) * 100, 0.01) as averageMargin

  from &dsn
  WHERE datepart(BETDATE) > '31DEC2010'd AND datepart(BETDATE) <'01JAN2012'd 
  AND bet_type = 'SGL'   
  group by 1,2
 /* HAVING sum( case when floor( (qtr(datepart(betdate))+1)/2) = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) >= 4 */
  order by username desc, yearsemiyear asc;
```

quit;

How can I restrict this to customers who had at least 4 bets in the first half of the sample? If I uncomment the HAVING clause I have there, it only seems to return rows for the first half, and no second half rows are returned. I tried putting the restriction into the WHERE clause, but apparently you can't put a summary function in that CLAUSE.

How should I do this?

Thanks

Comment: FYI, in the future I'd suggest creating a simple dataset that you can include in these posts as datalines so it's easier to show you useful examples, rather than having to come up with sample data on our own to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the calculated columns in your HAVING clause.  See for example:

```
proc sql;
select country, sum(case when region='EAST' then Actual else 0 end) as east_act,  
sum(case when region='WEST' then Actual else 0 end) as west_act
from sashelp.prdsale 
group by 1
having east_act > 120000;
quit;
```

Specific to your problem, you should change your HAVING clause to

```
HAVING firstHalfBetcount ge 4
```

I'm looking at this again, though, and I think your problem is that you're grouping by half year - so you wouldn't get records from the second half, as you'd never have a record that has both first half and second half data (if your data is as I think it is).  You either need to not group by half year, and do this at the overall year level, or not separate first half/second half in columns.

If your goal is to get rows for both, but only include rows for people with 4 first half bets, you may need to create this table and then join it to a query of people with at least 4 first half bets, or use a where (select... ) subquery to filter down to those people; you can't do it with just grouping and having.

Comment: No problem. Will include some data in cards at the top in future.

Comment: I have a condition in a sum in the code above to calculate firstHalfBetcount and secondHalfBetcount as they are calculated using the sum() function. Is it possible to do the same with mean() i.e. for the following line 'round(mean((winnings - stake) / stake) * 100, 0.01) as averageMargin'. Can this be surrounded by a case/when to separate the margin for each semi-year?

Comment: Made some edits, as looking at your query and thinking about your data, I think there is something different wrong.

Comment: You're right. It would be better to aggregate it up to the full year to put everything on one row, so I've done that now.

Comment: else . end will be ignored by the mean (or, leave off the else, though you will get a warning).

Comment: Bingo. Thanks again. Great stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have the issue, too. After detailed compare the right code and mine, I found that the problem is group by, which is only character variables. If we use numerical ones, then the error comes

Comment: Hi @jiayi , please elaborate your answer . Perhaps the inclusion of working code and highlighting the problem area will add lot more value to the post.

Comment: You can compare the question code and the answer code, the big change is that:   group by 1,2 or group by 1. In the case, if 1 and 2 are both categorical variables then there won't be error. However, if either 1 or 2 is numerical variable then there will be error.